# Order products in Catalog > Category OpenCart variable by ( MIX - RANDOM )

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

There is a way to make this code and sort the products not by default OpenCart values but to mix the results in category?

Instead of listing products in category by price but mixing them, random results,

Thank you!

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'p.price';
}
```

Comment: `$sort` goes directly into SQL query? If so `rand()` should give random ordering.

Comment: If you order by just any random value each time, then that is likely to interfere with pagination though - assuming that is handled in the usual way, by requesting a certain range of records each time, and not the whole data set at once. To avoid that, the random generator would have to be _seeded_ with a value that stays constant across all the pagination requests for this data set.

Comment: I have made this but somehow it won't work. :(

if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
   $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
  } else {
   if (in_array($this->request->get['category_id'], array(120, 122, 121))) {
    $sort = 'DESC';
   } else {
    $sort = 'price - p.price'; 
   }
  }